# Batch Script Delete Folders & Files (Except One) From Remote PCs

Tags: batch-file

We have multiple workstations that we need to do this on, and would like to batch script it (PowerShell is not an option for this particular task).

On each PC, we need to kill a specific process ("univmgr.exe"), then delete all subfolders and files from the following parent directory: C:\DRS\TEMP, except one subfolder named "DGNUser10" (as well as excluding everything inside the DGNUser10 subfolder).

I'm able to get my test script to work when I run it locally on a single test machine:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im univmgr.exe /t
pushd "C:\DRS\TEMP" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="DGNUser10" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd
```

But when I try to target a text file list of computers (list.txt), something is horribly wrong with my syntax, but I haven't yet been able to figure out what it is or how to fix it...  Here's the current script I've been tweaking and testing:

```
:Start
cls
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (list.txt) do (

taskkill /f /im univmgr.exe /t
for /D %%D in ("C:\DRS\TEMP") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="DGNUser10" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
    )
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
    )
)

Goto End

:End
```

Comment: Your FOR command is certainly reading the LIST.txt file but you never use it nor do you ever try to attempt to target those computers to do what you need to do.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `taskkill /?`  But that is only half your problem.

Comment: The second part of your problem is accessing the remote computers hard drive.  If you have permissions to do so you can use the administrative share.  So you can use the `PUSHD` command just like in your first script.  `pushd \\computername\C$\DRS\TEMP`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Squashman!  That info was exactly what I needed in order to get in the proper frame of mind AND figure out how to modify the code to get it to work!  What's the best way for me to post the "answer" with the proper code?  I don't wanna give myself credit for posting the correct modified code, but I still wanna be able to share how your tips helped me get a properly modified and working script! :)

Comment: You can certainly post your own answer.  I have no problem with that.  My helping style is too lead the horse to water. Teach a man to fish....etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Squashman's gentle and spot-on leading, I was able to figure out what I needed to modify in my code in order to get the script working!

Here's the updated script:

```
:Start
cls
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (list.txt) do (

taskkill /s \\%%A /f /im univmgr.exe /t
pushd "\\%%A\c$\DRS\TEMP" || exit /B 1
for /D %%D in ("*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="DGNUser10" rd /S /Q "%%~D"
)
for %%F in ("*") do (
    del "%%~F"
)
popd

)

Goto End

:End
```